# How to compare similar related keys in array of hashes in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have an array of hashes, let's say

```
arr = [
  {:country=>"Portugal", :rating=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average", :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto"},
  {:country=>"USA", :rating=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great", :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham"},
  {:country=>"UK", :rating=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor", :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London"}
]
```

I'm trying to check through this array for key:value matches between hashes based on the linked columns (`rating1`/`rating2`, `city1`/`city2`) and give the matches an `id` as a new key:value pair. I also trying to search for multiple search terms.

E.g. if searching for "city", it should return:

```
{:country=>"Portugal", :rating=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average", :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto", :match=>"0"},

{:country=>"USA", :rating=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great", :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham", :match=>"1"},

{:country=>"UK", :rating=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor", :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London", :match=>"1"}
```

If searching for "city" and "rating" together, it should return:

```
{:country=>"Portugal", :rating=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average", :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto", :match=>"1"},

{:country=>"USA", :rating=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great", :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham", :match=>"1"},

{:country=>"UK", :rating=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor", :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London", :match=>"1"}
```

(Because Portugal's `rating1` matches with USAs `rating2`, and USA's `city2` matches with UK's `city1`)

So far I can match on a single column and with a single attribute, but I'm having trouble when trying to work with the similar columns and multiple attributes:

```
def search_id(elements, search_key)
  # Get rid of elements with nil values.
  target_elements = elements.reject {|e| e[search_key].nil?}

  result = []
  id = 0

  # Iterate through target_elements
  target_elements.each do |currentElement|

    # Check for elements with same value in the result array
    match = result.find {|previousElement| currentElement[search_key] == previousElement[search_key]}

    if match
      currentElement[:id] = match[:id]
    else
      currentElement[:id] = id
      id += 1
    end

    # Add element to result
    result << currentElement
  end

  result
end
```

Comment: A Hash is not a database. Why are you trying to do complex queries and joins with Hash objects?

Comment: It's a practice exercise, so I'm not using any external libraries/GEMS and doing it just within Ruby

Comment: Yes, but real database functionality is non-trivial. Some of what you want to do is easy, but some of it isn't. There are a number of other users asking similar questions right now like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72418664/1301972. They're bad questions because solving them correctly requires handling a lot of edge cases. See https://github.com/ruby/dbm, https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/DBM.html, https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html, https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby for better alternatives.

Comment: You wrote, "Because Portugal's `rating1` matches...", but Portugal only has keys `rating` and `rating2`. Presumably, that should read "Because Portugal's `rating` matches..." *or* the keys `rating` in all hashes should be changed to `rating1`. Either way, the question is not clear. It is understood this is just an exercise, which is fine, though it should also be understood that this would be a very poor code design. Also, you need a closing `']'` to your definition of `arr`. That's important as readers will cut-and-paste it to test their code.

Comment: Shouldn't USA have `:match=>'2'`, as it matches Portugal on `"great"` and the UK on `"Birmingham"`, or is `:match` not a count, but effectively is `true` (="1") or `false` (="0")?

Comment: Please answer my question and add the missing `']'` to your code.

Comment: Added. The match value would be a boolean rather than count in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the keys `:rating` should be `:rating1`.

Based on my understanding of the question, you could obtain the desired return values by executing `add_counts` below.

```
def add_counts(arr, *key_matches)
  arr.map { |h| h.merge(match: count_matches(arr, key_matches, h).to_s) }
end
```

```
def count_matches(arr, key_matches, h)
  arr.count { |g| match_either_pair?(key_matches, h, g) } - 1
end
```

```
def match_either_pair?(key_matches, h, g)
  key_matches.any? { |key_pair| match_either_key?(h, g, key_pair) }
end
```

```
def match_either_key?(h, g, key_pair)
  (h.values_at(*key_pair) & g.values_at(*key_pair)).any?
end
```

---

Let's try it.

```
arr = [
  {:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
   :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto"},
  {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great", :city1=>"NYC",
   :city2=>"Birmingham"},
  {:country=>"UK", :rating1=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor",
   :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London"}
]
```

```
add_counts(arr, [:city1, :city2])
  #=> [{:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
  #     :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto", :match=>"0"},
  #    {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great",
  #     :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham", :match=>"1"},
  #    {:country=>"UK", :rating1=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor",
  #     :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London", :match=>"1"}]
```

```
add_counts(arr, [:rating1, :rating2], [:city1, :city2])
  #=> [{:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
  #     :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto", :match=>"1"},
  #    {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great",
  #     :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham", :match=>"2"},
  #    {:country=>"UK", :rating1=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor",
  #     :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London", :match=>"1"}]
```

---

Let's examine each of the methods in reverse order. I assume `arr` is as above and

```
key_matches = [[:rating1, :rating2], [:city1, :city2]]
```

**match_either_key?**

Suppose

```
h = arr[0]
  #=> {:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
  #    :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto"}
g = arr[1]
  #=> {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great",
  #    :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham"}
```

First,

```
key_pair = [:rating1, :rating2]
```

```
a = h.values_at(*key_pair)
  #=> ["Great", "Average"]
b = g.values_at(*key_pair)
  #=> ["Good", "Great"]
c = a & b
  #=> ["Great"]
c.any?
  #=> true
```

As `c.any? => true` there is no need to test for

```
key_pair = [:city1, :city2]
```

but had we done so,

```
a = h.values_at(*key_pair)
  #=> ["Lisbon", "Porto"]
b = g.values_at(*key_pair)
  #=> ["NYC", "Birmingham"]
c = a & b
  #=> []
c.any?
  #=> false
```

**match_either_pair?**

As before, assume

```
h = arr[0]
  #=> {:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
  #    :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto"}
g = arr[1]
  #=> {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great",
  #    :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham"}
```

then

```
key_pair = key_matches[0]
  #=> [:rating1, :rating2]
match_either_key?(h, g, key_pair)
  #=> true
```

The latter was computed above. Since it was found to return `true` there is no need to compute the value for `key_matches[1]`.

**count_matches**

Again, we assume

```
h = arr[0]
  #=> {:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
  #    :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto"}
```

The first value passed to the block is `h`:

```
g = arr[0]
```

As `h == g #=> true` both pairs obviously match:

```
match_either_pair?(key_matches, h, g)
  #=> true
```

Next

```
g = arr[1]
  #=> {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great",
  #    :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham"}
```

and, as previously determined,

```
match_either_pair?(key_matches, h, g)
  #=> true
```

Lastly,

```
g = arr[2]
  #=> {:country=>"UK", :rating1=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor",
  #    :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London"}
match_either_pair?(key_matches, h, g)
  #=> false
```

(Trust me on the last calculation.)

As `arr[0]` matches itself and `arr[1]`, `count` returns `2`.

We subtract `1` to obtain the number of matches with other elements of `arr`.

**add_counts**

```
h = arr[0]
n = count_matches(arr, key_matches, h)
  #=> 1
s = n.to_s
  #=> "1"
h.merge(match: s)
  #=> {:country=>"Portugal", :rating1=>"Great", :rating2=>"Average",
  #    :city1=>"Lisbon", :city2=>"Porto", :match=>"1"}
```

```
h = arr[1]
n = count_matches(arr, key_matches, h)
  #=> 2
s = n.to_s
  #=> "2"
h.merge(match: s)
  #=> {:country=>"USA", :rating1=>"Good", :rating2=>"Great",
  #    :city1=>"NYC", :city2=>"Birmingham", :match=>"2"}
```

```
h = arr[2]
n = count_matches(arr, key_matches, h)
  #=> 1
s = n.to_s
  #=> "1"
h.merge(match: s)
  #=> {:country=>"UK", :rating1=>"Dismal", :rating2=>"Poor",
  #    :city1=>"Birmingham", :city2=>"London", :match=>"1"}
```

---

If the key `:match` is to be interpreted as a boolean, where `'1'` and `'0'` represent `true` and `false` respectively, change `add_counts` to the following.

```
def add_if_match(arr, *key_matches)
  arr.map { |h| h.merge(match: [count_matches(arr, key_matches, h), 1].min.to_s) }
end
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks! If I wanted to assign unique match values for each member of the array how might I go about that? For example, if a hash has no matches for any of the searched keys, it gets an ID.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: My apologies, English is not my first language. 

I mean for every hash in the array to have a unique identifying ID in place of the "match" one you specified. When two or more of the hashes in the array match based on the search keys, they share the same identifying ID. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. You will need to submit that as a separate question.